# Static analyzer says I have the potential leak of an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, static-analysis

This is an object I made to do some flash cards.  The first method (I left out the main part) generates a NSMutabaleArray of Card objects with the passed in operator and works fine.  The second method, "drawFromDeck" gets called on a Deck object from my view controller and also works fine, but the Static Analyzer says I may be leaking an object.

Here is the code.

```
#import "Deck.h"

@class Deck;
@implementation Deck

@synthesize cards;

- (id)initDeckWithOperator: (NSString*)mathOper {

...

 return self;
}

- (id)drawFromDeck {
    int index = random() % [cards count];
    Card* selectedCard = [[cards objectAtIndex:index] retain];
    [cards removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    return selectedCard;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you're leaking an object. You should

```
return [selectedCard autorelease];
```

The reason being you've `-retain`ed the `selectedCard`, so you've got the responsibility to `-release` it. But you can't use `-release` since it must be valid after the function ends, so you need to use `-autorelease` to transfer the ownership to the auto-release pool.

Of course, methods calling `-drawFromDeck` shouldn't `-release` its return value.

Comment: I'd say it would be clearer to just not retain the card in the first place. He has no reason to take ownership at that point.

    Card* selectedCard = [cards objectAtIndex:index];

Comment: @Joshua Weinberg - However, if he did that it may be deallocated at the instant -removeObjectAtIndex: was called.  By using autorelease, at least it will exist long enough to be returned from the method.

Comment: tested my assumption, I was wrong. Makes sense now that I think about it.